# How to combine Python and Html in this situation to work?

Tags: python, html, css

Well I'm trying to make some kind of calculator on html and css site with python which needs to work like there is 2 values 1 value is constant which is
`num1` = `2`. `num2` is the input value and I want to know how to make python react in real time at site and show output which is same as: `print(num1 * num2)`.

Python code:

```
<script>
num1 = 2
num2 = int(input())

print(num1 * num2)
</script>
```

HTML code:

```html
<input type="number" name="num2">
```

How to make it show output instantly when is input typed?

Comment: You can't use python in browser... Script tag is for javascript.

Comment: @TrueTiem ok but witch tag is for the python ? if i try <% %> its not working :/

Comment: as i said. You can't use python in browser. If you want to use python as "back-end" you need a web framework for python. Like django (https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: Why does this need to be python at all? a client side language would be pretty capable of handling this without calls to a backend

Comment: @TrueTiem ok thanks, is there any otther way to does this ?

Comment: @Sayse which language it can be for this simple function, i thought easiest is to do it with python ?

Comment: There is Brython (and others?): https://brython.info/

Comment: It's much simpler with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can neither directly do it in Python nor will you be able to do. Because the language of Web is JavaScript and only JavaScript. But two scripts are used as interpreted script as I have heard. They are **CoffeeScript** & **TypeScript**. If you still want to use python, you have to use frameworks like Django or Flask. Then you have to make **AJAX** call (still through JavaScript) and reload the part of the Page you want to.

Your python may code look like below:

```
@route("/calculate?<int:input>")         # this is a dummy example web framework. Doesn't exists in real life
def calculate(request, input):
    return http_response(str(input * 2))
```

Then pass your url *http..../calculate?<the number here>* with AJAX call with JavaScript. Then reload the result  part of the page. But I don't recommend doing this. Though python is easy in this case but you will find yourself in complexity with AJAX. You should only use python when you need to something on BackEnd. Such as accessing the server. Or using a feature that is not supported in any other programming language. If you need to use the **eval** function, you can use python

**Edit**: A new tool has come to realize your dream. It's brython which finally made writing python codes in browser instead of JavaScript. It is interpreted to JavaScript like CoffeeScript but you will not be able to use python modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use python in browser... Script tag is for JavaScript. You have to understand the difference between client and server-side programming languages.
But if you want a javascript solution for this:

```
<input type="number" name="num2">
<span id="output">
<script>
    // first number
    var num = 2;
    // get input and convert to a number
    var inp = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value) || 0;
    // do math
    var out = num * inp;

    // do things with output
    console.log(out); // this will send output to console log
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out; // this will write output to span
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant make python to work on the browser, although its possible but not advisable, i advice you use javascript

Javascript

```
<script>
 var num1 = 2
 var num2 = document.querySelector('input')
 document.getElementById('#output').innerHTML = num1 * num2
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="num2">
<strong id="output"></strong>
```

All should well my friend

Comment: Did you use # in getElementById ? And didn't get value at num2

Comment: So sorry, that was a mistake